# Accessing variables from my index.js in another file

Tags: node.js, scope

I am trying to make a bit of code execute as if it was in the index.js of my nodejs app.
I have the following code:

index.js

```js
var data = [];
function populateData(){
   for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      data.push(i);
   }
}
populateData();
require('./other.js')();
```

other.js

```js
module.exports = function(){
   console.log(data);
}
```

However, this tells me data is not defined. Is there any way to read the data variable like this?
I tried

```js
require('./other.js').apply(null);
```

and

```js
require('./other.js').apply(this);
```

However neither worked for me

Comment: Why not pass data as argument? That is much better approach than using data directly.

Comment: It would be a better approach in this case however im more interested in being able to run functions from one file in the scope of a different file. This example is a significantly simplified demo for the concept im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another module for common variable.

- common.js

```js
module.exports = {
  data: []
}
```

- index.js

```js
const common = require('./common');
const other = require('./other');

function populateData(){
   for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      common.data.push(i);
   }
}
populateData();
other.test();
```

- other.js

```js
const common = require("./common");

module.exports = {
    test: function(){
       console.log(common.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a good solution (And one I plan to implement on future projects) I am currently working on a project that would require a lot of reworking in order to run it this way. Is there a way to directly run the other.js function under the index.js scope?

Comment: Then, you can simply use global variables like `global.data = xxx` https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

Comment: Ah, thanks, this will work with what I am trying to do, however, is there a way to simply change the file scope a function is executing in?

Comment: On current module structure, `index.js` needs `other.js`, and also `other.js` needs `index.js` as a requirement. I think this is not good approach, so you should move `populateData()` to single module with `data`, and just call it from one side (`other.js`), like `populateData(); console.log(data);`, or call `populateData()` once when the module initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data to the file like this

index.js

```
var data = [];
function populateData() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push(i);
  }
}
populateData();
require('./other.js')(data);
```

other.js

```
module.exports = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};
```

Comment: I need a more general way to access any variable. Perhaps is there a way for me to pass all current variables as an argument without having to manual put every one of them into an object?